# How to access the position of radiobuttonlist items in asp?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a radiobutton list in asp.
 I need to access the items of radiobutton list one

```
 while (reader.Read())
            {
                RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(reader["options"].ToString());


            }
```

what I need to do is check the first item in the list. 
I am very beginner in ASP. Just started couple of day back.

Answer (score 0):

To check the first item just use:

```
RadioButtonList1.Items[0].Selected = true;
```